# Slideshow effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, touch, slideshow

How do I make a slideshow effect, similar to http://red.mts.ru/?

There are big images on the background, you can click and drag them (touch effect). 
Images are scaled to fit the screen.

Have you seen some similar jquery gallery scripts, or how to reproduce it by picking different plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Flexslider](http://flex.madebymufffin.com/)

A responsive slider plugin that supports touch input.

Comment: seems it supports touch swap on smartphones only. There is no option for desktop. So its not usefull.